# Symfony 2 : Custom user provider

Tags: security, ldap, symfony

Since this article http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html has not been written yet, has anyone an idea of how to do that ? (In my case it would be using LDAP authentication).

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help you get started you can check out my blog post which outlines how to create a very basic user provider system:

http://clintberry.com/2011/custom-user-providers-symfony2/

**EDIT:** This post only covers the custom User Provider. To use LDAP authentication you will need to create your own Authentication Provider as well or use a third party library. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html

Comment: I can't see in your tutorial where you're calling your web service to retrieve users oO

Comment: The actual loading of the user is done inside the user class. In my instance, I am loading users via a REST api. I have an entity base class that handles the connection to the rest service to load the users. You can see the function that gets called in my provider inside the loadUserByUsername($username) function. It calls the User::find() function which is defined in my base class. My post will only show you how to create the provider, but you still need to create your own custom entity which handles user loading and other functions. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

This first thing I would suggest you is to do a search for a LDAP bundle on the great website [KnpBundles](http://knpbundles.com/) (results [here](http://knpbundles.com/search?q=LDAP)). I saw two results. If you are willing to use an external bundle, you could just use of the two given in the results.

If you prefer to create your own bundle for this task, what I would suggest is to inspire you from these two bundles. Another useful suggestion is to check the [FOSFacebookBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle). It is in no mean related to LDAP but, they implements their own provider, so all the glue is there to implement your own.

Just a small notice, if you are developing against Symfony2 master branch, it is good to know that security factory registration has changed a bit. So, be carefull when looking at other bundles to be sure what version they are targeting.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Matt

Comment: I tried one LDAPBundle (Boris Morel's one) but couldn't get it working (Invalid type for path "security.factories". Expected array, but got string). I don't like the other one (openSky) cause you have to import Zend framework into your project (31Mb), which is a non-sense to me since we choose to use Symfony oO

Comment: I understand. Then, you should check those implementations to learn how to implement your own authentication provider.